# Springboot+JPA(Hibernate)+Oracle AbstractMethodError not define or inherit an implementation of isValid(int)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc

- JavaJDK 1.13
- Springboot 2.2.6
- Spring Data JPA
- Oracle 10g

I'm a beginner in using Spring boot, and when I tried running the demo program, it reported exceptions as such:
`Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract boolean isValid(int)' of interface java.sql.Connection.`

I've tried many solutions on the web (like upgrade the driver to ojdbc7 or higher, while I've been 
 using ojdbc8 from the begining, and even tried ojdbc8 and ojdbc10 downloading from the website of Oracle 19c, but no one worked).

Following @JensSchauder 's suggestions, I peeked into the class `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` and found there was really no such method called `boolean isValid(int)` but `boolean isValidLight(int)` instead.

Here is the screenshoot:
[ScreenShoot Here, boolean isValidLight(int var1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XAan.png)

Here list the ojdbcs I've tried:

- ojdbc8:12.2.0.1
- ojdbc7:12.1.0.2
- ojdbc8:19.3.0.0(in use)
- ojdbc10:19.3.0.0

How should I suppose to fix this? Maybe give up Oracle?

Thanks for all your tips.

Comment: Try
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.ojdbc/ojdbc8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <version>19.3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yeah, I've tried the ojdbc driver downloaded from 19c(19.3.0.0) before, but it remained the same. Should I delete other ojdbc driver from the .m2 directory?

Comment: The error suggest that you have ojdbc14 (or maybe ojdbc5 if that exists) on your classpath.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, you are right. I found them(ojdbc14) under `%JavaHome%\lib`. They seems to come from oracle10g. I would try renaming them to see if it would cause any probem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is really fishy here. The method Hikari is looking for was introduced in Java 1.6 so it should definitely be there with `ojdbc8`.

I'd try the following to better understand what is going on.

1. check that the dependency is actually properly downloaded.
2. find the `Connection` class in the IDE and inspect it if it has the `isValid` method or not. 
   I strongly suspect it has.
3. add a break point to the line where Hikari is throwing the exception and check what kind of object it is inspecting.

This already might give enough hints to debug this, if not please update your questions with the information you found.

Comment: I thought I've found the issue. I located the class `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection` and found that it really doesn't have `boolean isValid(int)` but `boolean isValidLight(int)` instead. How should I suppose to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you seeing inherited methods as well in that view? So `T4Connection` does not implement `Connection`? Or does it implement a really old version of `Connection` without `isValid`? Also is it coming from the jar file it should come from?

Comment: Problem was solved. It was caused by I had ojdbc14.jar under my classpath and I forgot to check it. But anyway, Thanks very much for your answer, and sorry for taking up your time.